# Django: Dynamically generate ChoiceField values from another model object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to implement a Django form with dynamically generated ChoiceField options.

> In my views.py I have defined the following (relevant) methods:

```
from .forms import OptionForm

def get_choice():
  return # like this [(q.optionA, q.optionA), (q.optionB, q.optionB), (q.optionC, q.optionC), (q.optionD, q.optionD)]

# how can I pass q to this __init__ method
class OptionForm(forms.Form):
  options= forms.ChoiceField(choices= [])
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OptionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
    self.fields['options'].choices = get_choice()


def viewtest(request, test_pk):

# get the test object containing all the questions
# each question contains four options using which I want to generate ChoiceField options corresponding to each question
# each option is available as q.optionA, q.optionB q.optionC & q.optionD
  test= get_object_or_404(Test, pk= test_pk)
  options= []
  for q in test.questions.all():    
    opform= OptionForm() # how do I pass q.optionA, q.optionB q.optionC & q.optionD here to dynamically provide ChoiceField options?
    options.append(opform)
  return render(request, 'tests/test.html', {'test': test, 'options': options})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get choices from model, `ModelChoiceField` is a better option. Find more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot solve my problem, as I need to have separate ChoiceField values for each question.

Comment: Can you please explain it in more detail?
I guess you should be able to do that by passing your queryset in ModelChoiceField.
`forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.filter() )`